# Image Overlay / Qgis raster projected incorrectly on Leaflet JS

Tags: qgis, raster, leaflet

In leaflet js I added an image to my map (image overlay).
The image is a georeferenced jpeg, and it's a raster generated by Qgis.
In leaflet I setted the image bound points correctly (NE and SW), and I tested this even after the map is rendered.
So, if the **extreme points (NE and SW) are corrects**, the internal image points do not correspond to the real coordinates, as you can see in the image (see the detail of railway tracks):
[image: overlay.png]

Any clue?

Comment: Which projection is the image in? Do you have any control points?

Comment: Image projection is in UTM33 WGS84. File .jwt contains this informations: 0.301796417216513 ; 0.000000000000000 ; 0.000000000000000 ; -0.301811376146870 ; 708474.757291694870000 ; 4520957.402170119800000 . The last values represent NE point coordinate, then convert it to LatLon (40.81316823608622 - 17.47176623188087). In Qgis I made sure that the SW limit point is 711519.02 - 4519312.78 (LatLon 40.79758814357056 17.507270150411824).

Comment: I suggest you reproject the raster into EPSG:3875 (web mercator, Leaflet's default) and try again (unless you're using proj4leaflet to use UTM33 in the browser)

Comment: Should be EPSG:3857? (Not 3875)

Comment: I always confuse those two :-)

Comment: I regenerated the raster with projection EPSG: 3857 and now the positioning is perfect. Thanks Ivan!

Comment: Then let me write this as an answer instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the projection of your raster file matches the display projection (i.e. the projection used by Leaflet).

Remember that Leaflet works in EPSG:3857 (aka "web mercator") whereas aerial imagery might be in a different projection. Even if the corners of your raster match, different projections mean that your raster might warp in unexpected ways.

You can either warp your raster image into EPSG:3857, or use [proj4leaflet](https://github.com/kartena/Proj4Leaflet) to make Leaflet display everything in a different CRS - both these solutions should work.

Comment: I regenerated the image raster with projection EPSG:3857 and now the positioning is perfect. Thanks!